# How to load & extract text content from Adobe Indesign file , C#?

Tags: c#, adobe-indesign

I want to load Adobe Indesign file, then I want read all text content of file(extract text data). How can I it in C#?

Comment: in what format? more info please

Comment: My file include image & text. I want get all text content of file in c#. for example in c# code, I want load InDesignn file, then access to all items of file, then get just text(string) conten that typed in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indesign dll can be added as a COM reference to a C# application. It does provides methods to get file information.

Edit: I do not have these things installed on the computer so can't really write some code. But [this](http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/app_notes/id_obj_model.htm) link should help.

Comment: I add this reference , but I cant access for load and get data method. please get me method name for load text data from InDesign file layers.